# Ошибка на python 3.9 local variable 'loginInput' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

```
from tkinter import *
window=Tk()
window.title('Тест по истории')
window.geometry('1920x1080')
def btn_click():
    x=loginInput.get()
    symb=[']',']','>', '<',',','.','\\','/','{','}','!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')',';',':',"'",'"',"№","?"]
    for i in x:
        if i==' ' or i in symb:
          c=1
          break
        else:
           с=0
if c==1:
    frame=Frame(window,bg='red')
    frame.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
    frame=Frame(window,bg='red')
    frame.place(rely=0.4,relx=0.4,relwidth=0.2,relheight=0.2)
    title=Label(frame,text='Введите своё имя нормально!', bg='white',font=100)
    title.pack()
    loginInput=Entry(frame,bg='green')
    loginInput.pack()
    btn=Button(frame,text='Клик',command=btn_click)
    btn.pack()
else:
    frame=Frame(window,bg='red')
    frame.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
    frame=Frame(window,bg='red')
    frame.place(rely=0.4,relx=0.4,relwidth=0.2,relheight=0.2)
    title=Label(frame,text='Привет ' + x, bg='white',font=100)
    title.pack()
frame=Frame(window,bg='red')
frame.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
frame=Frame(window,bg='red')
frame.place(rely=0.4,relx=0.4,relwidth=0.2,relheight=0.2)
title=Label(frame,text='Введите своё имя', bg='white',font=100)
title.pack()
loginInput=Entry(frame,bg='green')
loginInput.pack()
btn=Button(frame,text='Клик',command=btn_click)
btn.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: уточните, что должен делать код

Comment: Все что вы пишите снаружи функций до запуска `window.mainloop()` выполнится до создания окна, а у вас тут какая-то проверка имени, которое пользователь не мог никак успеть ввести (т.к. окно еще не существует). А то что у вас в функции находится, выполнится когда пользователь нажмет на кнопку. Соответственно и проверки в этой же функции должны быть.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка здесь - `x=loginInput.get()` (6 рядок), Вы не указали что такое `loginInput` но уже хотите получить из него что-то

Comment: Я посмотрел комментарии и понял в чём ошибка, спасибо, как в таком случае сделать, чтобы при нажатии кнопки на месте старого окна появлялось новое, то есть менялась лишь просто информация в окне, а не новое создавалось.